# not shown products on frontend after migration from magento 1 to magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.3, migration

I did the migration with magento1 to magento 2.3
Everything works fine, but no products are displayed on frontend.

I tried all the methods that I found on the Internet, but it did not help.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: you have run command? `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Comment: check if salable qty is not zero, and inventory_stock_1 table is in view

Comment: Was the migration successful? Did you use Magento Data Migration Tool for the migration? Where you able to find products in the backend?

Comment: Yes i did php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: Yes, migration was successful. I see products on backend, but don't displayed on frontend

Comment: Where you able to find any information in debug and exception logs. Check for indexer status as when the reindexing was done last. So in frontend are you being displayed "Unable to find Products" or similar message.

Comment: @DenisMaksiura you can open this  `var/migration.log` file and check error log

Comment: I repeat again. Migration was successful. Out of 65,000 products, only 3 are displayed on frontend.